# In Eclipse, how to know which parameter is the cursor on a Java Method?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

In Eclipse IDE, I have a Java method with a lot of nullable parameters

```
src.myCrazyFunction(year, name, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I want to call the function with city parameter 'NY'.
By the use of Javadoc tooltip, I have to count parameters until "String city" and then:

```
src.myFunction(year, name, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 'NY', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

Counting parameters it's really boring each time I have to use this method.

Could I know the name of the parameter where the cursor is? CTRL+SPACE would be for all the parameters...

Comment: You should really refactor that method so that it doesn't have so many parameters.

Comment: @puhlen Better sympathize with the guy slaving away on an enteprrise project called The Midnight of Human Reason.

Comment: When hitting CTRL+space, eclipse shows the parameter in **bold** for me. like this: http://imgur.com/a/vZTxh , (and when moving the cursor, the parameter under the cursor changes to bold)

Comment: @nos I stole your comment for [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39533385/5221149), but I did credit you for the very nice image.

Answer (score 2):

Press Parameter Hints / Context Information - `Ctrl+Shift+SPACE`

[image]

Comment: This does not work with the current version of Eclipse IDE. When I put my cursor at the method parameters and press Ctrl+Shift+Space, it will give me a selection of methods of the current class, but not of the method of the object I am trying to call.

Answer (score 1):

First thing : you should change this method if it's really like that, it's insane. Second, I don't know what you really mean, but in Eclipse when you will type `src.` it will show you all the available methods, click on your method and code will be generated with parameter names as arguments (for you to change that). For example if you type `"someString".indexOf` and you pick a method it will generate `"someString".indexOf(ch, fromIndex)` (those are not variables or anything, those are parameter names specified in `indexOf` method declaration, they will give compile-time error if you don't change them). You can see your parameter names, so it's fast to change specific one to `NY`, you will still have to write the nulls yourself tho. I hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: I agree this method is insane but sometimes developement design is decided by other people.
The problem is I have to review code with functions like this, and they are written before. So, I arrive at line 280 of code and I see a function with 20 parameters. I would like to know which parameter is 'NY' in the list of parameters

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @nos in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532602/in-eclipse-how-to-know-which-parameter-is-the-cursor-on-a-java-method#comment66379722_39532602), pressing `ctrl+space` in Eclipse will popup a tooltip that highlights (in **bold**) the parameter where the cursor is, as illustrated in in image provided by @nos:
[image]

However, that still requires IDE support and is relatively cumbersome to use *(you have to position cursor and trigger it to use it)*, so you should consider other means.

No method should take 24 parameters, but if you absolute must, then your should comment all parameter values that are not self-explanatory, e.g. `year` and `name` are probably explanatory enough, but values like `null`, `0`, `false`, `42`, `true`, etc. does not convey *meaning*, so you should comment them:

```
src.myFunction(year,
               name,
               /*address1*/null,
               /*address2*/null,
               /*city*/null,
               /*state*/"NY",
               /*zipcode*/null);
```

That way a casual observer will know exactly what the values mean.

Another way to do this is to wrap all the parameter values in a POJO and use the builder pattern.

```
src.myFunction(new MyPojo()
               .setYear(year)
               .setName(name)
               .setState("NY"));
```

Comment: This code is written and I have to review it.
I like the idea of commenting parameters and defining a POJO but the code is written, so I have to comment all lines of this kind or define POJOs.
If the function call has been written before, CTRL+SPACE in Eclipse doesn't work for the parameter where the cursor is

Comment: CTRL+SPACE works fine for already written calls, e.g. place cursor before any `null` value, press CTRL+SPACE, then select the method (make sure to select the correct one if there are overloads).

Comment: Thanks Andreas but it shows all the parameters but I would like to know in which parameter the cursor is.

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot in this answer, the parameter where the cursor is, is in **bold**. Pressing CTRL+SPACE pops up a dialog, listing method overloads (and some other options). *Selecting* a method by **double-clicking** mouse, **or** highlighting with arrow keys and **pressing ENTER**, will then show what you see in this answer.